# Convenções de Código em C#

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, convenções

Eu tenho alguma experiência com Java e C. Recentemente, eu peguei um projeto em C#. Gostaria de saber se existe um **guia de estilo** da Microsoft ou de alguma outra entidade para saber como é o estilo de programação em C#.

Comment: desculpe, não tinha achado o ícone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe. [No MSDN tem o guia ***C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)

Comment: Alguém sabe me dizer o que tem de errado com a resposta?